# Restful paginate with python

Tags: python, rest, pagination

I'm getting data using Python via a rest API call as follows...

```
result = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.somesite.com/v0/someLink?api_key=aaabbbccc"))
```

There's a 100 max results built into the API so I have to paginate in python.

After making the first call, **result.nextPage** returns a code that I then have to pass to the next API call like...

```
result2 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.somesite.com/v0/someLink?api_key=aaabbbccc&nextPage=someCode"))
```

And so on until I'm through all pages.

Does python have any in-built mechanism to handle pagination like this?

I could write a clumsy loop myself but am unsure about

1. How to handle waiting for each page so I know I can proceed with the next call
2. How to handle the 'no more pages' event without erroring
3. How to combine the results of all calls into 1 variable after making all calls

Appreciate any thoughts at all on the most elegant way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does python have any in-built mechanism to handle pagination like this?

No.

Write a `while True:` loop with a `break` statement if there are no more pages to load.

> How to handle waiting for each page so I know I can proceed with the next call

`urllib2.urlopen` is not asynchronous. Your code will block (i.e. wait) until the request is done.

> How to handle the 'no more pages' event without erroring

That depends on the API you are using. I would expect that `result.nextPage` is empty/not set on the last page.

> How to combine the results of all calls into 1 variable after making all calls

Append them to a list as you go. Pseudo code:

```
url = "initial URL"
results = []

while True:
    current_page = request(url)
    results.append(current_page)
    if (another page available):
        url = "new url with next page code"
    else:
        break
```

I wholeheartedly recommend that you use [the `requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of the very bare-bones `urllib2.urlopen`.

Comment: thank you - that worked perfectly and I'll check out the requests module later